# disable multiple answer checkboxes after passing the page in moodle 2.5

Tags: php, moodle

I am using moodle version 2.5
I want multiple answers disabled after submitting and going to next page (question).
I mean one could go back to see the question and chosen answer but unable to correct the answers and encountering disabled checkboxes.
thank you